# Laravel 5.2 MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I got `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error on my **Laravel 5.2** project, while I was adding Add Comment section.

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentsController@store');
```

Here is my CommentsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\Comment;
use App\Http\Requests;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Post $post)
    {
        Comment::create([
            'body' => request('body'),
            'post_id' => $post->id
            ]);

        return back();
   }
}
```

and here is my view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
    <h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1>
    {{ $post->body }}
    <hr>
    <h5>Comments</h5>
    <div class="comments">
        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
            <li class="list-group-item">
            <strong>
                {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}: &nbsp;
            </strong>
            {{ $comment->body }}
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <!-- Add Comment -->
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
            <form method="POST" action="/blog/public/posts/{{ $post->id }}/comments" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="body" placeholder="Your Comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

The variables `$post` and `$comment` passed successfully to the view as retrieving the content and comment is working fine, but when I try to submit a new comment I got `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

Comment: Can you post the part of your routes file handling this form please?

Answer (score 1):

1. Provide your route a name

   ```
   Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentsController@store')->name('comments.create');
   ```
2. Add the csrf token and use the helper method [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes) to access the route in your form

   ```
   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('comments.create', ['post' => $post->id]) }}" >
       {{ csrf_field() }}
       <div class="form-group">
           <textarea name="body" placeholder="Your Comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
       </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
       </div>
   </form>
   ```
3. Change your function signature

   ```
   public function store($post)
   {
       Comment::create([
           'body' => request('body'),
           'post_id' => $post
       ]);

       return back();
   }
   ```

Comment: i did this and still same problem.

Comment: Please do `composer dump-autoload` and then try again

Comment: @hesham try changing your function signature

Comment: still the same problem, i pushed my project into github to easily check the code. Hope you can check it : https://github.com/HeshamAbusaif/Blog-Laravel

Comment: Try placing `Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments` before `Route::get('/posts/{post}'`

Answer (score 1):

your form action should be like this

```
/posts/{{ $post->id }}/comments
```